# General error: 1364 Field 'parent_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, database, laravel, oop, laravel-8

***please help my...
please help me when I want to post a comment the error is displayed***

*SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'parent_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `comments` (`comment`, `user_id`, `commentable_id`, `commentable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)*

**class CommentController.php**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $comment = new Comment;

        $comment->comment = $request->comment;

        $comment->user()->associate($request->user());

        $post = Post::find($request->post_id);

        $post->comments()->save($comment);

        return back();
    }

    public function replyStore(Request $request)
    {
        $reply = new Comment();

        $reply->comment = $request->get('comment');

        $reply->user()->associate($request->user());

        $reply->parent_id = $request->get('comment_id');

        $post = Post::find($request->get('post_id'));

        $post->comments()->save($reply);

        return back();

    }
```

**models Comment.php**

```
use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
    }
```

**models Post.php**

```
  use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')->whereNull('parent_id');
    }
```

**2020_09_18_082706_create_comments_table.php**

```
public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();

            $table->text('comment');

            $table->integer('commentable_id')->unsigned();

            $table->string('commentable_type');

            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('comments');
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qObxM.png
```

Comment: what should the `parent_id` be of a comment that does not have a parent? also the way this is setup it has to have a value

Comment: Provide a value for `parent_id` or make it `nullable()` in the migration.

Comment: What is `parent_id` even supposed to be, since you have a morphable relationship to a commentable object?

Comment: Set the parent_id nullable() in your migration file.

Comment: https://github.com/david656558/Laravel_comment.git         (it's link working, comment in 2 random product (polymorphic laravel 8)